# How to convert string[] to ArrayList?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an array of strings. How can I convert it to System.Collections.ArrayList?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to use an `ArrayList`? Use `List<string>` instead.

Comment: Why not just leave it as the Array (or more accurately, IEnumerable<string>) and use the LINQ Extensions?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
string[] myStringArray = new string[2];
myStringArray[0] = "G";
myStringArray[1] = "L";

ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();
myArrayList.AddRange(myStringArray);
```

Answer (score 44):

Just use ArrayList's constructor:

```
var a = new string[100]; 
var b = new ArrayList(a);
```

Comment: The lowest of low hanging fruit.

Comment: Appears cleaner and a smaller code-footprint than the accepted `.AddRange()` approach.

Answer (score 3):

System.Collections.ArrayList list = new System.Collections.ArrayList( new string[] { "a", "b", "c" } );

Answer (score 1):

```
public stringList[] = {"one", "two", "three"};
public ArrayList myArrayList;

     myArrayList = new ArrayList();
     foreach (string i in stringList)
     {
         myArrayList.Add(i);
     }
```