# Insert Values from string[] arrays to an ArrayList of records

Tags: c#, arraylist, arrays

I will add the values in the String[] in to the Arraylist. But, I want to access those string values from the ArrayList.

I tried this way.

```
private void Form1_Load()
{
    fr = new string[5] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
    bd = new string[5] {"a", "b","c", "d", "e"};
    m = new ArrayList();
    dosomething();
}

private void dosomething()
{
    string[] record = new string[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        record[0] = "1";
        record[1] = fr[i];
        record[2] = bd[i];
        m.Add(record);
    }
}
```

I don't want to use the for loop is that any other way to do this???

Comment: Is your used programming language Java?

Comment: @reporter : `private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` -> no it looks like .Net

Comment: why did this get the android tag?

Comment: Not in Java. I need C#

Comment: updated mine to be `C#`

Comment: @Sarwan I updated the title to match the code, feel free to rollback if I misinterpreted your question...

Comment: Found this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701788/how-to-convert-string-to-arraylist hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use dictionaries. It is in my opinion the quickest way to store / access data. Also, with arraylists, at runtime, it performs a dynamic transtyping, which makes you loose so much time.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe want to use :

```
        fr = new string[5] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
        bd = new string[5] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
        m = new ArrayList();
        fr.ToList().ForEach(_item => m.Add(new String[]{ "1", _item,bd[fr.ToList().IndexOf(_item)]}));
```

But I would prefere a solution like Fares already recommented...Use A `Dictionary`

[Dictionary - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/xfhwa508.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need an ArrayList. A generic list might be more suitable for you.

```
var fr = new string[5] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
var bd = new string[5] {"a", "b","c", "d", "e"};

int i = 1;
var results = fr.Zip<string, string, string[]>(bd, (a,b) => {
    var v = new string [3] { i.ToString(), a,b }; 
    i++;
    return v;
}).ToList();
```